# Show and hide paragraphs when link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What would be the easiest way to change the paragraphs according to the image you click. Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M7DhU/1/) of what the content looks like minus the display of the paragraphs. The paragraphs below the images would be shown 1 at a time depending on the image you click.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="memberPhotoWrapper">
        <div class="memberPhotos">
            <a href="#"><img class="member1Photo" src="http://s30.postimg.org/gpichz4n1/portraitplaceholder.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="member2Photo" src="http://s30.postimg.org/gpichz4n1/portraitplaceholder.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="member3Photo" src="http://s30.postimg.org/gpichz4n1/portraitplaceholder.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="member4Photo" src="http://s30.postimg.org/gpichz4n1/portraitplaceholder.jpg" alt="" title=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="memberIntros">
        <div class="member1Intro">
             <h3>User Name</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="member2Intro">
             <h3>User Name</h3>
            <p>PSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="member3Intro">
            <h3>User Name</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="member4Intro">
            <h3>User Name</h3>
            <p>PSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7DhU/5/)?

Comment: and everyone else who took the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JS:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var intros = document.getElementsByClassName("intros");

for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        img[i].onclick = function() {
            reset();
            intros[i].style.display = "block"; 
        }
    })(i);
}

function reset() {
    for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
        intros[i].style.display = "";
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7DhU/5/)

Answer (score 0):

use hide / show function with jquery library

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var m1= true;
    $( ".member1Photo" ).click(function() {
        if(m1) {
            $('#member1').hide();
            m1=false;
        }else{
            $('#member1').show();
            m1=true;
        }
        });

    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djedjex/M7DhU/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple piece of code (using jQuery).

```
$('.memberPhotos img').click(function() {
    $('.memberIntros .current').hide('slow');
    $('#'+this.id+'_intro').show('slow');
    $('#'+this.id+'_intro').addClass('current');
});
```

example here http://jsfiddle.net/8kgwR/1/

you will need to change some class/id names to suit.